# Passing the only GPU through to a VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, x-server

I would like to use a Windows 10 VM on a Linux host.

If there is only one graphics processor (i.e. a graphics card but no integrated graphics) how can I pass this through to the VM?

I would rather not reboot the host in and out of some headless mode, but I wouldn’t mind closing all of my programs if that’s what it takes to disconnect the X server.

([Relevant forum post](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/running-linux-without-a-graphics-card/112852/1) from a couple of years ago)

Comment: What hypervisor?

Comment: I was planning to use qemu although I would be happy to use any if something else will work